# Непонятное название торта

Tags: значение-слова

Объясните, пожалуйста, глупому мне: есть такой торт, который называется "Захер". Многие смеются над этим словом, а что оно вообще означает?
Спасибо заранее

Comment: Иностранное название, наверное)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да всего лишь имя собственное.

> «За́хер» (нем. Sachertorte) — шоколадный торт, изобретение австрийского кондитера Франца Захера.

(Вики)  
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%80_%28%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%29